# SQL Query-How to remove table spool

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to fine-tune following query to remove table spool. It has 10 million records. I've given my execution plan below.

Query:

```
SELECT          
    ATT.EMPCODE 
   ,ATT.EMPNAME
   ,ATT.FROMDATE
   ,ISNULL(EMPPER.FIRST_NAME.'')  
   ,ISNULL(EMPPER.MIDDLE_NAME.'') 
   ,ISNULL(EMPPER.LAST_NAME.'')
   ,DET.[SUPERVISOR]
   ,ATT.[DEPARTMENT]
   ,SHI. [SHIFT TIME]
   ,DET.IN_TIME
   ,LAT.UT_TIME
   ,SHI.SHIFT_NAME
   ,PRO.[ACTUAL_TIME]
   ,LAT.[LATE]
FROM
    Attendance ATT
    INNER JOIN        [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.EMPLOYEE EMP 
       ON ATT.N_ID=ATT.EMPID
    LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT * 
         FROM [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.VIEW_ATTENDANCE_DETAILS 
         WHERE TODATE BETWEEN 'NOV 01 2016' AND 'NOV 15 2016'
        ) DET 
        ON ATT.N_ID=DET.N_ID AND ATT.FROMDATE=DET.TODATE
    LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT * 
         FROM [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.VIEW_EMPLOYEE_SHIFT 
         WHERE TODATE BETWEEN 'NOV 01 2016' AND 'NOV 15 2016'
        ) SHI 
       ON ATT.N_ID=SHI.N_ID 
          AND ATT.FROMDATE=SHI.TODATE
    LEFT JOIN   
        (SELECT * 
         FROM [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.PROCESSDETAILS 
         WHERE TODATE BETWEEN 'NOV 01 2016' AND 'NOV 15 2016'
        ) PRO 
        ON ATT.N_ID = D.N_ID 
           AND ATT.FROMDATE=D.TODATE
    LEFT JOIN    
        (SELECT * 
         FROM [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.LATETIME 
         WHERE TODATE BETWEEN 'NOV 01 2016' AND 'NOV 15 2016'
        ) LAT 
        ON ATT.N_ID=E.N_ID AND ATT.FROMDATE=E.FROMDATE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN    [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.VIEW_LEAVE_STATUS LEV 
            ON LEV.N_ID=ATT.N_ID AND ATT.FROMDATE=LEV.FROMDATE 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.REPORTS RPT 
            ON ATT.N_ID=R.N_ID
        LEFT JOIN   [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.EMPLOYEE_DETAIL EDTS H 
            ON R.RM_ID=H.N_ID       
        LEFT JOIN  [172.241.2.147].HIST_DATT.DBO.EMPLOYEE_PERSONAL EMPPER Z ON ATT.N_ID=Z.N_ID AND ATT.FROMDATE =Z.FROMDATE
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY 
     ATT.N_ID
    ,ATT.FROMDATE
     OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8690)
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: If you provide an XML of the actual plan (use pastebin.com or something similar), definitions of all tables and indexes, number of rows in each table and result, somebody may be able to give an answer. The way it is, there is not enough information to say anything.

Comment: Several of your join conditions are messed up and don't even reference the table they are supposed to be joining so you may well find if you fix that the row count goes down anyway as you are getting accidental cross joins.